# apostrophe in json object to add slash

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting a json object like this

```
{
    "First": "MyName's",
     "Last": "MyLast"
}
```

I want to stringify this object so that 's in value become `\'`
it could be 's or 'S or 'anything

I am using JSON.stringify(json_obj) but its giving me string

```
"{"First":"MyName's","Last":"MyLast"}"
```

you can see MyName's I want this to MyName\'s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a regex replace incase if you going to have more than once such values,

```
.stringify(data).replace(/'/g, "\\'")
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qMsyg/2/

Answer (score 5):

after you've stringified the `json` just apply a `replace("'", "\'");`

```
JSON.stringify(json).replace("'", "\'");
```

Or you may use a *[replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter)* into `stringify()` method

```
JSON.stringify(json, function(key, value) {
   return value.replace("'", "\'");
})
```

---

**NOTE:** `replace("'", "\'")` will **only replace the first occurrence**, as pointed out by @vega. If you have more values to escape use a regular expression (like `replace(/'/g, "\\'")`).

Choose the one which best fits your needs

Comment: I think a regex replace with `/g` is better..

Comment: @MichaelTodd Isn't the `replace("'", "\'");` is going to modify the 1st matched `'` alone.. incase if he has more values with a `'`